# Lua If statement evaluation

Tags: if-statement, lua, evaluation

If I use:

```
local a, b ,c 
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1

if a == (b or c) then x end
```

I only ever get a response if b is true c is not evaluated

If I change this to

```
if (a == b or a == c) then x end
```

This correctly evaluates either b or c

p.s. I am using this Lua in a Fibaro Home Centre 3 Home automation system.

Comment: In lua `or` basically means "if the left side is not nil or false take that, otherwise take the right side"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check wether a equals b or c this is the correct sytnax:

> if a == b or a == c then end

Your parenthesis are ok but not required.

In

```
local a, b ,c 
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1

if a == (b or c) then end
```

`(b or c)` resolves to `b` and thus `if a == b then end`

The reason for that is called short-circuit evaluation. `b` is `1` and hence a true value. So the `or`ed expression will be `true` no matter of `c`'s value. So there is no reason to evaluate `c`.

From https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5

> Both **and** and **or** use short-circuit evaluation; that is, the second
> operand is evaluated only if necessary. Here are some examples:
>
> ```
>  10 or 20            --> 10
>  10 or error()       --> 10
>  nil or "a"          --> "a"
>  nil and 10          --> nil
>  false and error()   --> false
>  false and nil       --> false
>  false or nil        --> nil
>  10 and 20           --> 20
> ```

Same here:

```
if a == b or a == c then end
```

If `a` equals `b`, Lua will not check if `a` equals `c`. This is not too obvious but if you would have something like:

```
local a = 1
function b() print("b") return 1 end
function c() print("c") return 1 end

if a == b() or a == c() then end
```

Lua would not call `c` if the return value of `b` equals `a`